# Why do binary tree traversals need helper functions? LeetCode problem 110

Tags: python, binary-tree, helper, depth-first-search

I was looking at solutions for LeetCode problem [110. Balanced Binary Tree](https://leetcode.com/problems/balanced-binary-tree/description/):

> Given a binary tree, determine if it is height-balanced.
>
> A **height-balanced** binary tree is a binary tree in which the depth of the two subtrees of every node never differs by more than one.

I noticed that all the community answers incorporate a helper function. Similarly, other binary tree traversal questions use helper functions as well. When I try to implement a solution without using a helper, it fails some test cases, despite being similar in function.

Why is this? Below the accepted answer and my code without the helper.

Accepted solution:

```
class Solution(object):
    def isBalanced(self, root):
        def dfs(root):
            if not root:
                return [True, 0]
            left = dfs(root.left)
            right = dfs(root.right)
            balanced = left[0] and right[0] and abs(left[1] - right[1]) <= 1
            return [balanced, 1 + max(left[1], right[1])]
        return dfs(root)[0]
```

My code:

```
class Solution(object):
    def isBalanced(self, root):
        if not root:
            return [True, 0]
        left = self.isBalanced(root.left)
        right = self.isBalanced(root.right)
        balanced = left[0] and right[0] and abs(left[1] - right[1]) <= 1
        return [balanced, 1 + max(left[1], right[1])]
```

Comment: You return a list instead of a boolean. Notice that the accepted solution returns `dfs(root)[0]`, which means it returns the boolean in the output of `dfs(root)`.

Answer (score 1):

A helper function is practical here, because there are two different measures at play here:

- The height of a tree
- Whether the tree is balanced or not

The code challenge is to only return the second of these two, but to determine that, you need to use the first information. So somehow you need to return the first information from a recursive call. But if you have implemented that, this cannot be the final function, because that one needs to return the second measure only (a boolean), and not the first (a height).

That's why you will quickly come to code that has two functions: one to gather both measures for the subtrees, and one that extracts the second measure to finally return as answer.

### Alternatives

If you really wanted to, it is possible to do this with just one function, but then you need to store somewhere else what the heights are of the subtrees. Since you cannot pass this on via the return value (which must be a boolean), you need to store it somewhere else. Candidates for storing this additional information include:

- An attribute of `Solution`: a dictionary that collects for each node its height.
- An extra, optional parameter to `isBalanced`: an object that must be mutated by the callee to store the height.
- Use and mutate the node itself to store its height.

Here are implementations of each of these three alternatives:

#### Alternative 1: "global" dictionary

As LeetCode creates a new `Solution` instance for each test case, you can use the `__init__` method to initialise a dictionary that will be dedicated to one test case, and can be used to register the height of each node as it is visited.

This solution is less interesting because it involves O() auxiliary memory.

```py
class Solution:
    def __init__(self):
        self.heights = {}

    def isBalanced(self, root):
        if not root or not (self.isBalanced(root.left)
                        and self.isBalanced(root.right)):
            return not root
        leftheight = self.heights.get(root.left, -1)
        rightheight = self.heights.get(root.right, -1)
        self.heights[root] = max(leftheight, rightheight) + 1
        return abs(leftheight - rightheight) < 2
```

#### Alternative 2: Extra "return" parameter

Here the function pushes the height of the current node into a list that is passed as extra argument. The caller can then find the height in that list. As LeetCode will not pass that extra argument, you need to give it a default value and only populate the list when it was passed as argument.

```py
class Solution:
    def isBalanced(self, root, heights=None):
        childheights = []
        if not root or not (self.isBalanced(root.left, childheights) 
                        and self.isBalanced(root.right, childheights)):
            return not root
        # make sure it has 2 entries:
        childheights += [-1] * (2 - len(childheights))  
        if heights is not None:  # only pass on the height when not the root
            heights.append(max(childheights) + 1)
        return abs(childheights[0] - childheights[1]) < 2
```

#### Alternative 3: Mutating nodes

This abuses the `val` attributes of node instances to store the heights. It is like we received "unused" memory from the caller (as `val` has no role to play here), which we can use to store this extra information.

```py
class Solution:
    def isBalanced(self, root):
        if not root or not (self.isBalanced(root.left) 
                        and self.isBalanced(root.right)):
            return not root
        leftheight = root.left.val if root.left else -1
        rightheight = root.right.val if root.right else -1
        # abuse val attribute to store the node's height
        root.val = max(leftheight, rightheight) + 1
        return abs(leftheight - rightheight) < 2
```

**Unrelated remark:** the standard definition of height is that a leaf node has height 0, and so a `None` (empty tree) would correspond to height -1. This is why I have used -1 as default values in all these alternatives. You can also use 0 like in the code you shared, but then it does not truly represent the node's height, but the number of levels in the tree it roots. For the algorithm it doesn't make a difference, it is just a matter of naming things with standard terminology.